# Must constexpr expressions be captured by a lambda in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, c++14, constexpr

Here is a piece of code that won't compile in MSVC 2015 (ignore the uninitialized value access):

```
#include <array>
int main() {
    constexpr int x = 5;
    auto func = []() {
        std::array<int, x> arr;
        return arr[0];
    };
    func();
}
```

It complains that:

```
'x' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified
```

But `x` is a `constexpr`!  `x` is known at compile time to be `5`.  Why does MSVC kick up a fuss about this?  (Is it *yet* another MSVC bug?)  GCC will happily compile it.

Comment: It's just as likely to be a GCC extension that it accepts it.

Comment: GCC has too many extensions nowadays. Clang will not compile this as is proper.

Comment: Clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cd455e49015b829

Comment: [Clang accepts this if you change `std::array<int, x>` to `std::array<int, +x>`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/R3pFxjmn6VMoVQJb).

Comment: [icc accepts this as-is](https://godbolt.org/g/er7NcD).

Comment: This was fixed with VC 16.1: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/367326/problems-with-capturing-constexpr-in-lambda.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code is well-formed. The rule from [expr.prim.lambda] is:

> If a *lambda-expression* or an instantiation of the function call operator template of a generic lambda odr-uses (3.2) `this` or a variable with
>   automatic storage duration from its reaching scope, that entity shall be captured by the *lambda-expression*.

Any variable that is odr-used must be captured. Is `x` odr-used in the lambda-expression? No, it is not. The rule from [basic.def.odr] is:

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `ex` is odr-used by `ex` unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to `x` yields a constant expression (5.20) that does not invoke any non-trivial
>   functions and, if `x` is an object, `ex` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression `e`, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to `e`, or `e` is a discarded-value expression (Clause 5).

`x` is only used in a context where we apply the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and end up with a constant expression, so it is not odr-used, so we do not need to capture it. The program is fine. This is the same idea as why this example from the standard is well-formed:

> ```
> void f(int, const int (&)[2] = {}) { }   // #1
> void f(const int&, const int (&)[1]) { } // #2
>
> void test() {
>     const int x = 17;
>     auto g = [](auto a) {
>         f(x); // OK: calls #1, does not capture x
>     };
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Answer (score -2):

Even though `x` is a `constexpr`, it is no different from any other object, otherwise, and follows the same rules with regards to scoping. There are no exceptions to scoping rules for `constexpr`s, and a lambda must be coded to explicitly capture it.

Comment: Is there then a way to capture it but allow me to use it as a template parameter as in my code?

Comment: That's another question.

Comment: clang would allow you to just capture it `[x]() {...}` and then use it as a template parameter, yet GCC doesn't. I'm confused.

Comment: @Bernard just make it `static`, no need to capture.

Comment: Capturing it by value, seems to be sufficient: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/icc.txt and there's nothing to be confused here. C++ is arguably one of the most complicated modern programming language, and it is not totally unexpected that some compiler occasionally fails to do things right in an obscure corner case. I haven't investigated if, indeed, capturing it by value is the kosher thing to do, and gcc chokes on it; but if so, opening a bug in gcc's bugzilla should get the ball rolling on fixing it.

Comment: @Sam On MSVC, it doesn't work whether you capture it by value or by reference.

Comment: No, this isn't the case, -1.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Looks like I should find out how to file bug reports for both MSVC *and* Clang (as mentioned by @cpplearner).  Personally, I've never filed a bug report for anything before.