# Why can I "captureless-capture" an int variable, but not a non-capturing lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20

The following function is valid (as of C++20):

```
void foo() {
    constexpr const int b { 123 };
    constexpr const auto l1 = [](int a) { return b * a; };
    (void) l1;
}
```

even though `l1` does not capture anything, supposedly, it is still allowed to "captureless-capture" the value of `b`, as it is a `const` (it doesn't even have to be `constexpr`; but see @StoryTeller's comment).

But if I try to capture something more complex in a new lambda:

```
void foo() {
    constexpr const int b { 123 };
    constexpr const auto l1 = [](int a) { return b * a; };
    (void) [](int c) { return l1(c) * c; };
}
```

This fails to compile. Why? The compiler should have no trouble calling `l1` from within the lambda; so why is `b` ok for captureless-capture, and `l1` isn't?

[See this on GodBolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/ocv3b6fa1)

Comment: Pretty sure this is because of ODR-Use.  Let me see if I can't find the section I'm thinking of

Comment: dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873788/can-i-use-a-constexpr-value-in-a-lambda-without-capturing-it

Comment: better target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610429/must-constexpr-expressions-be-captured-by-a-lambda-in-c

Comment: "*as it is a const (it doesn't even have to be constexpr)*" - Integral types are special. It does have to be constexpr, even if by the "implicit constexpr" property the integral types posses when declared const.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has to do with odr-use.

First, from [[basic.def.odr]/10](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10):

> A local entity is odr-usable in a scope if:
>
> - either the local entity is not *this, or an enclosing class or non-lambda function parameter scope exists and, if the innermost such scope is a function parameter scope, it corresponds to a non-static member function, and
> - for each intervening scope ([basic.scope.scope]) between the point at which the entity is introduced and the scope (where *this is considered to be introduced within the innermost enclosing class or non-lambda function definition scope), either:
>
>   - the intervening scope is a block scope, or
>   - the intervening scope is the function parameter scope of a lambda-expression that has a simple-capture naming the entity or has a capture-default, and the block scope of the lambda-expression is also an intervening scope.
>
> If a local entity is odr-used in a scope in which it is not odr-usable, the program is ill-formed.

So in this example, `a` is odr-usable but `b` is not:

```cpp
void foo() {
    constexpr const int b { 123 };
    constexpr const auto l1 = [](int a) { return b * a; };
    (void) l1;
}
```

And in this example, similarly, the `a` and `c` are odr-usable, but neither `b` or nor `l1` are.

```cpp
void foo() {
    constexpr const int b { 123 };
    constexpr const auto l1 = [](int a) { return b * a; };
    (void) [](int c) { return l1(c) * c; };
}
```

But the rule isn't just "not odr-usable", it's also "odr-used". Which one(s) of these are odr-used? That's [[basic.def.odr]/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#5):

> A variable is named by an expression if the expression is an id-expression that denotes it. A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression E is odr-used by E unless
>
> - x is a reference that is usable in constant expressions ([expr.const]), or
> - x is a variable of non-reference type that is usable in constant expressions and has no mutable subobjects, and E is an element of the set of potential results of an expression of non-volatile-qualified non-class type to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ([conv.lval]) is applied, or
> - x is a variable of non-reference type, and E is an element of the set of potential results of a discarded-value expression ([expr.context]) to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied.

For the `b * a` case, `b` is "a variable of non-reference type that is usable in constant expressions" and what we're doing with it is applying "the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion". That's the second bullet exception to the rule, so `b` is *not* odr-used, so we don't have the odr-used but not odr-usable problem.

For the `l1(c)` case, `l1` is also "a variable of non-reference type that is usable in constant expressions"... but we're not doing an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on it. We're invoking the call operator. So we don't hit the exception, so we are odr-using `l1`... but it's not odr-usable, which makes this ill-formed.

**The solution** here is to either capture `l1` (making it odr-usable) or make it `static` or global (making the rule irrelevant since `l1` wouldn't be a local entity anymore).

Comment: Aren't constexpr const variables implicitly static?

Comment: Also, I want to change the names of the variables in the question not to clash with your quotes from the standard, to make things less confusing.

Comment: Also, the first bullet of odr-usable is not relevant to our case, right? So perhaps 'snip' it out?

Comment: @einpoklum No, `constexpr` variables are implicitly `const`, but `constexpr` and `static` are orthogonal.

Comment: I think that merits a followup question...