# Why aren't constexpr const scoped variables implicitly static?

Tags: c++, lambda, static, constexpr, storage-duration

<sub>(Following to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960411/1593077):)</sub>

```
void foo() {
    constexpr const auto my_lambda = [](int z) { return z+1; };
}
```

Apparently, `my_lambda` is "not static". In what sense is it not-static, other than not officially defined to be? Why should it not be implicitly static, seeing how it [seems to meet the definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables)?

Answer (score 5):

> In what sense is it not-static

Its not static in the sense that it doesn't have static storage duration. It has automatic storage duration.

For most purposes, it doesn't matter whether the storage duration is static or not because the initialisation and destruction of the object are trivial, and the storage isn't used at all. Still, this demonstrates an important difference:

```
auto* foo() {
    constexpr const auto my_lambda = [](int z) { return z+1; };
    return &my_lambda; // dangling pointer
}

auto* foo_static() {
    static constexpr const auto my_lambda = [](int z) { return z+1; };
    return &my_lambda; // OK
}
```

Comment: But it doesn't have "automatic storage duration". I can use its value in, say, a static_assert which may spew an error - meaning its value is available before the program ever starts. And it doesn't change, and continues to be available, afterwards.  .... ah, but yes, the address. If I were to use `consteval`, would taking the address be malformed?